# Python Caesar Cipher Using Turkish Alphabet Array

Tags: python, cryptography, caesar-cipher

The first for loop(for i in range ) is not working properly even though the second works as it should be.

You can find the code and the loop that I have problem below:

```
alpLower = ["a","b","c","ç","d","e","f","g","ğ","h","ı","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","ö","p","r","s","ş","t","u","ü","v","y","z"]
alpUpper = ["A","B","C","Ç","D","E","F","G","Ğ","H","I","İ","J","K","L","M","N","O","Ö","P","R","S","Ş","T","U","Ü","V","Y","Z"]
encrypt=[]
b=0

text = input("Please enter a text:\t")
shift = int(input("Please enter the shift value:\t"))

for c in text:

#problem occurs at the loop below
for i in range(0,29,1):
    if c == alpLower[i]:
        b+=1
        c = alpLower[(i+shift)%29]
        encrypt.append(c)
        break
    else:
        b=0
#problem occurs at the loop above

for i in range(0,29,1):
    if c == alpUpper[i]:
        b+=1
        c = alpUpper[(i+shift)%29]
        encrypt.append(c)
        break

    else:
        b=0

if b==0:
    encrypt.append(c)

print("\nEncrpyted text:")

for i in encrypt:
    print(i,end="")
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation please ?

Comment: And can you provide an example of the expected output & what you have, or the error message ?

Comment: if b == 0, i.e not in the alphabets, should the character not be encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

I would reorganize your code, to make it look more like this:

```
def ceasercypher(steps, word):
        alpLower,  alpUpper = ["a", "b", "c", "ç", "d", "e", "f", "g", "ğ", "h", "ı", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "ö", "p", "r",
                    "s", "ş", "t", "u", "ü", "v", "y", "z"], ["A", "B", "C", "Ç", "D", "E", "F", "G", "Ğ", "H", "I", "İ", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "Ö", "P", "R",
                    "S", "Ş", "T", "U", "Ü", "V", "Y", "Z"]
        answer = []
        for letter in word:
            if letter.isupper():
                answer.append(alpUpper[int((steps + alpUpper.index(letter))%len(alpUpper))])
            if letter.islower():
                answer.append(alpLower[int((steps + alpLower.index(letter))%len(alpLower))])
        return "".join(answer)
print(ceasercypher(0, "ağV"))
```

just for fun, you can always try to write it short!
but if you work in a team or, want to be able to understand it later this is bad practice.
I call it "programmers useless flex, and root of a lot of bugs"

```
def ceasercypher(steps, word):
    alpLower,  alpUpper = ["a", "b", "c", "ç", "d", "e", "f", "g", "ğ", "h", "ı", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "ö", "p", "r",
                "s", "ş", "t", "u", "ü", "v", "y", "z"], ["A", "B", "C", "Ç", "D", "E", "F", "G", "Ğ", "H", "I", "İ", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "Ö", "P", "R",
                "S", "Ş", "T", "U", "Ü", "V", "Y", "Z"]
    return "".join([alpUpper[int((steps + alpUpper.index(letter))%len(alpUpper))] if letter.isupper() else alpLower[int((steps + alpLower.index(letter))%len(alpLower))] if letter.islower() else " [INVALIDCHAR] " for letter in word])
print(ceasercypher(1, "ağVZ%K%"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to loop through each element in the list to know what it's index is, you can just get the index with the element using index().

```
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'giraffe', 'elephant', 'monkey']
  
# Will print the index of 'giraffe' in animals
print(animals.index('giraffe'))
```

Output:

[image]

Applying it to your code:

```
for c in text:
    if c in alpUpper:
        i = alpUpper.index(c)
        c = alpUpper[(i + shift) % 29]
        b += 1
        encrypt.append(c)
    else:
        b = 0
```